# How to wait for result of two promises, then do something?

Tags: javascript, winjs

Well, subject. Can't figure out...

Condition: both promises start asynchronously and **not** one after another. Like this:

```
spashGoing.then(doSomethingForItself());
writingGoing.then(doSomethingForItself2());

DoSomethingAfterBothPromises()
```

P. S. I use promises from WinJS, not the ES2015/ES2016, but they don't have big defferences.

Comment: does "WinJS" have a `Promise.all` - note, your code looks wrong anyway, unless `doSomethingForItself` **returns** a function

Comment: WinJS doesn't seem to have a `Promise.all`, so have a look at `join`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2013/06/11/all-about-promises-for-windows-store-apps-written-in-javascript/

Comment: @EvanTrimboli OK will look for that

Comment: *they don't have big differences* - I wouldn't bet on that, at all ... like recent jQuery "deferreds" - they work 99% to spec, but that 1% will keep you guessing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Evan Trimboli with `.join`! See in comment under topic. I went to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2013/06/11/all-about-promises-for-windows-store-apps-written-in-javascript/) and found more beatiful solution [here](https://fknet.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/winjs-promises-lessons-learned/):

```
WinJS.Promise.join({ 
     p1: p1, 
     p2: p2, 
     m3: 3})
.then(function (args) {
    //args.p1 = null
    //args.p2 = promise with handle to file
    //args.m3 = 3
    console.log("Joined promise completed");
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Joined promise error '" + error + "' occured but was handled");
}).done();
```

Answer (score 4):

If WinJS promises are Promise/A+ promises

```
Promise.all([
    spashGoing.then(doSomethingForItself), 
    writingGoing.then(doSomethingForItself2)
]).then(function(results) {
    // do things with results
});
```

Well, answered too soon - WinJS promises are a typical example of Microsoft's *"let's do things just a little different"* attitude towards the web

Comment: Aha, I agree! Well, @EvanTrimboli helped me a lot with `.join`

Comment: yes, .join seems to be the *oh my god why would you do it that way, I'm talking to you Microsoft* answer